# Linearly ordered spaces and disconnectedness

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I have some troubles with the next exercise. I don't know how can I proced. Any hint? I really appreciate any help you can provide me.

> Prove that in a linearly ordered set (with the topology of order) the properties hereditarily disconnected, totally disconnected and zero-dimensional are equivalent.

First, the definitions that I have are the next:

1) $X$ is hereditarily disconnected if for all $x\in X$ we have that $C_x=\{x\}$, where $C_x$ is the connected component.

2) $X$ is totally disconnected if for all $x\in X$ we have that $Q_x=\{x\}$ where $Q_x$ is the quasi-connected component, i.e., $Q_x=\bigcap\{W\in B(X):x\in W\}$ where $B(X)$ denotes the set of all clopen sets of $X$.

3) $X$ is zero-dimensional if $X$ is $T_1$ and $X$ have a basis composed by clopen sets.

I know that $3\Rightarrow) 2$ and $2)\Rightarrow 1)$. Then, I have to prove $1)\Rightarrow 3)$. Then, I thought in the set $B(X)$. I want to prove that is a basis for the open sets. But is enough with take two different points $a,b\in X$ and prove that for all $x\in (a,b)$ (the open interval) there exist $A\in B(X)$ such that $x\in A\subseteq (a,b)$. Because $X$ is hereditarily disconnected then the set $(a,b)$ is disconnected. Let $(U,V)$ a separation of $(a,b)$, i.e., $U$ and $V$ are clopen sets in $(a,b)$. Then, without loss of generality $x\in U$. Because $(a,b)$ is open, then, $U$ is open in $X$ but, is it true that $U$ can be closed in $X$ too? I'm so stuck right here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that in general spaces zero-dimensional implies "totally disconnected" which in turn implies hereditarily disconnected. (Many textbooks and papers define totally disconnected as your (1), confusingly). In general the notions are different (even for metric spaces).

So assume that $(X,<)$ is an ordered space (so in the order topology) and that $X$ is hereditarily disconnected. Let $(a,b), a < b$ be an open interval in $X$, and $x \in (a,b)$. Then $(a,b)$ (which is an ordered space in its own right in the restricted order and then has the subspace topology, as a convex subset of $X$) is disconnected by assumption. A LOTS (linearly ordered topological space) is connected iff it has no gaps and no jumps (see [my answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2537962/4280)), so $(a,b)$ has a gap or a jump.

In the former case we can write $(a,b) = U \cup V$ both open and non-empty disjoint and convex and $U < V$, and neither $\max U$ not $\min V$ exists. Then $x$ is contained in either $U$ or $V$ and each set is a clopen neighbourhood of $x$ inside $(a,b)$. In the latter case we have a similar partition $U,V$ of $(a,b)$ but such that *both* $\max U$ and $\min V$ exist. Again $U$ and $V$ are clopen sets.

So the nice characterisation of connectedness of a LOTS immediately gives lots of clopen convex subsets when we have few connected sets.

Answer (score 0):

Assume distinct x,y in connected K.  Wlog, x < y.
Whence some clopen U subset (<-,y) with x in U.
U and its complement form an open disconnection of K.

Comment: What is $K$? Sincerely, I can't understand your answer.

Comment: @CarlosJiménez.    Just as I said, K is a variable over connected sets containing x and y.