# Prove that a subset of the real numbers is connected if and only if it is an interval

Tags: general-topology

A set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is connected if and only if it is an interval.

I know how to prove the $\Rightarrow$ direction by showing that if it isn't an interval it is disconnected, so I really only need help with the $\Leftarrow$ direction.

For the $\Leftarrow$  direction, I have a theorem which allows me to say that if (a,b) is connected then so are (a,b], [a,b), and [a,b], so it suffices to show (a,b) is connected.

I also know to start by assuming it is disconnected and search for a contradiction. I'm getting stuck after dividing (a,b) into the two separating sets.

Comment: IVT is your friend.  Remember disconnected means there is a continuous function to $\{0,1\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X,Y$ be components, and `x[0]` and `y[0]` be in $X$ and $Y$ respectively

```
n = 0
while x[n] != y[n]:
    z[0] = (x[n]+y[n])/2
    if X.contains(z[n]):
        x[n+1], y[n+1] = z[n], x[n]
    else:
        x[n+1], y[n+1] = x[n], z[n]
    n += 1
```

This defines Cauchy sequences $x_n, y_n, z_n$, and Cauchy sequences in the real line converge (this does require that you have a proof that Cauchy sequences converge that doesn't rely on intervals being connected; you might want to check with your instructor as to whether you can take this as given). The limits of these functions are equal, and is an accumulation point of both $A$ and $B$. But since $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, the complement of $A$ contains $B$, so being an accumulation point of a $B$ also means being an accumulation point of $A^C$. Since $A$ is open, $A^C$ is closed, so being an accumulation point of $A^C$ means being in $A^C$, which means it's not in $A$. Similarly, it's not in $B$. This shows that $A$ and $B$ don't cover the interval.

Another argument is to consider the function $I_A(x)$ that is $1$ for points in $A$ and $0$ otherwise. This is clearly not continuous. And yet every point in $A$ has an open interval around it in which $I_A$ is continuous, and similarly for $B$. Thus, for $I_A$ to be discontinuous, there must be some point in neither $A$ nor $B$ for it to be discontinuous at.

Answer (score 0):

Assume it's disconnected, then we can find $0_1,0_2 \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ open and disjoint such that $(a,b) = 0_1 \cup 0_2$, $0_1 \cap (a,b) \neq \emptyset$ and $0_2 \cap (a,b) \neq \emptyset$.

WLOG we can find an $x \in 0_1$ such that there exists a $y \in 0_2$ satisfying $x < y$. The set $M_x = \{z \in (x,b): (x,z) \subseteq 0_1\}$ is nonempty (because $0_1$ is open) and we can consider $m = sup \ M_x$. $m < b$ because we know that $y \in 0_2$ and therefore $m < y < b$ and because $0_1$ is open $m \in 0_2$. But $0_2$ is open so there exists an $\varepsilon > 0$ such that all $z$ satisfying $m-z < \varepsilon$ are in $0_2$. Now this is a contradiction because by construction of $m$ all $z$ satisfying $x < z < m$ have to belong to $0_1$.

So the key point is to investigate the values on the boundary of either $0_1$ or $0_2$ which are not $a$ or $b$. These points immediately give you the desired contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

I show in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2537962/4280) that a space in the order topology is connected iff it is complete and has no "jumps" (i.e. is densely ordered). It follows that $\Bbb R$ and all intervals in $\Bbb R$ are connected.